# Реализация окна ввода параметров

Tags: c++, qt5, дизайн

Реализую счётную программу для нескольких алгоритмов. Все параметры вводятся в отдельном окне. Есть общая часть настроек, есть специфическая под каждый алгоритм. Параметров очень много, поэтому все поля ввода помещены в QScrollArea.

Собственно сам вопрос: можно ли как-то аккуратно реализовать схлапывающиеся наборы полей ввода – коллапсеры. Почитал про QTreeWidget, и непонятно, можно ли в эту иерархию подавать QLineEdit и QLabel.
Или я не в том направлению смотрю? Может есть более удобные варианты ввода параметров?

[image: Окно настроек]

Comment: штатного решения нету, но посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476006/how-to-make-an-expandable-collapsable-section-widget-in-qt

Comment: В твоём случае, думаю будет достаточно просто вместо `setEnabled()` переключать `setVisible()` при смене алгоритма в combobox'e..

Comment: еще в Qt есть [State Machine Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html)... Достаточно удобная штука, если хорошо копнуть.

Comment: А может внизу сделать вкладки  (Tab) со специфическими параметрами, по вкладке под конкретный алгоритм? Тогда при выборе алгоритма из комбобокса (сверху) вы будете автомачески активировать вкладку со специфическими параметрами выбранного алгоритма. А посередине будут параметры общие, всегда доступные